# How to center dropdown menu under parent tab?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS/HTML setup http://jsfiddle.net/UDAUY/

How do I align the drop down menu field to center itself under the parent tab like this

```
| MENU 1 | MENU 2 | MENU 3 | MENU 4 |
-------------------------------------
    | Field 1 | Field 2 |
    ---------------------
```

instead of this,

```
| MENU 1 | MENU 2 | MENU 3 | MENU 4 |
-------------------------------------
         | Field 1 | Field 2 |
         ---------------------
```

which is how it looks right now. Also, can I set the width of the submenu ul container to adjust dynamically? Right now, I've set it to an arbitrarily high value, which works for all practical purpose, but would like to know if this is possible.

**EDIT**

I've added a bounty in the hopes of attracting better answers. I'm looking for a CSS only approach (no JS), and with relative units, not absolute. Also, the number of fields shouldn't matter (You don't have to worry about extremely long/wrapping issues.. However, changing from 2 to 4 shouldn't alter the centering).

Comment: I've fixed the use of `width: 300%`, but the dynamic centering is.. difficult :P

Comment: Are you avoiding javascript?  I'm sure this can be done with some jQuery positioning, but my CSS is rusty :)  I've also seen some pretty nifty things with the Superfish Menu plugin.

Comment: What is the oldest browser you need to support? IE8? IE7?

Comment: @thirtydot: oh, i don't care to support legacy browsers. This is for a personal academic site, not commercial. So pretty much all my target audience will be using either FF/Safari/Chrome and that is what I'm shooting for. I couldn't care less if things screw up in IE 6/7... if your hacks are not IE compatible, no problem.

Comment: @jbrookover: Well, I was trying to keep things purely CSS/HTML, as quite a lot of people have js disabled.

Comment: @d'o-o'b: Do you have stats that support your claim that "quite a lot of people" have js disabled on your site? You seem to be targeting modern desktop browsers. Stats seem to indicate there's only about 1% with js disabled in that segment on avg. Having the submenu absolute positioned for those visitors would seem a perfectly reasonable compromise to me, and you would save yourself A LOT of trouble.

Comment: @effata... i don't have stats to back me up. either case, it's not a big site and will hardly get 100 visitors/day. i don't know js and don't want to deal with it simply because i can't fix it if something goes awry or improve/extend it if i wanted to. the site isn't big enough to warrant my time investment in learning js. css/html, i can poke through and manage. if this cannot be done in css/html, i'm fine with that too. i just need to know that.

Comment: @d'o-o'b: If this was my project, i would settle for a left (or right) positioned menu for people without javascript, and a center positioned menu with javascript. It's by far the simplest solution. Centering stuff in relation to other things is very tricky in css.

Comment: What happens if the first tab has for example 6 sub menu items? Will the first sub menu items just go off screen? (it all has to be dynamic right?)

Comment: Agree with @Matijs, what do you want to happen when the `.subnav` links would overflow `#menu` (being centered in relation to the parent `<li>`)? Align right or left within the container, or stay literally centered beneath it - no matter how wide the number of sublinks would force it to be?

Comment: @d'o-o'b: I think it would help if you added more links and sublinks to the fiddle. Make it as close to what you would expect in the finished product as you can, so people get a better feel for what you're after. Or is this the exact amount of links?

Comment: @Madmartigan @Matijs, I thought of that, and the # of links isn't big enough to overflow. It might change at the most from 2 to 4, and the length of each might at the most be 1.5 times the present amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pure css centering that's "almost" done.

http://jsfiddle.net/gNanu/

It works for a dynamic amount of submenu items and centers properly as long as we have display: block on the wrapper. Once we remove that and hide the submenu, it gets a bit scewed. I will look at it a bit more and see if i can do anything else.

**Edit:**

This is probably the best you can do with css.
http://jsfiddle.net/gNanu/4/

It doesn't center perfectly sometimes, and i haven't done any cross browser testing.

Comment: that looks nice... the trouble i too had was in getting it to hide. looking forward to your suggestion/fix

Comment: You could use `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` to show/hide instead.

Comment: I did play around with that for a bit, but it still won't center perfectly. Seems to be some margin or padding that gets applied after the positioning.

Comment: thanks, Effata. Your solution looks good. Enjoy the 100 rep :)

Comment: Glad i could help, even though it's not perfect. But with some more polish it could be decent... :)

Answer (score 1):

http://pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm

(using display: inline; and text-align: center; would also work, but has its own drawbacks)

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
#menu .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 19pt;
    left: -25%;
    width:300%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Not sure thatl be rock solid in all broswers though. Excellent way to ask a question like this by the way...

Comment: That will not work, because it needs to be moved left by `(width(child)-width(parent))/2`. This appears to work because the size of the parent is approximately half the size of the child. If you add one more field and try this, it doesn't work.

Comment: you might need to go with a javascript solution in that case

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
menu {text-align:center}
fieldwrapper {margin:0 auto;}
field {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu .submenu {
position: absolute;
display: none;
top: 19pt;
width:300%;
margin: auto;
left: -100%;
text-align:center;
}

.submenu li {
background-color: #000;
margin-right: 1.5%;
padding-right: 3%;
padding-left: 3%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
}
```

This is what made it work for me.
Hope this is the answer you were looking for since i just joined and didnt bother to read all the answers... Just dived right in to it.

Comment: i like your solution for the fact that it's simple and required minimal changes to what was there. However, if the number of `li` increases, this introduces a second row. Adding `white-space:nowrap` fixes this, however it is no longer centered. I think this would require the use of a `div` as Effata has done. Anyway, +1 as this solution is acceptable when the number of `li`s are small.

Answer (score -1):

Parent need to be position relative, child absolute, then child must be inside parent. By cotrolling child `top:` (top must include parent height) and `left:` you can control it position. If you want centered you will need to use: `top: [parentheight]; left: 0;` Hope it helps :)

Comment: This does in no way center the submenu or contribute to a solution.