# Dynamically centering a CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to build a horizontal dropdown menu that has the 2nd level entries centered under their parent 1st level entry. Something similar has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384954/how-to-center-dropdown-menu-under-parent-tab), already.

But I'm not quite happy with that solution. I've built my dropdown menu in a very similar way, before I looked up the above solution. Please take a look at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/27UE8/1/

But it has one side-effect that I don't like: The wider the dropdown, the more I can go to the right (in my case) of the dropdown without making the dropdown disappear. This is because I'm working with a wrapper element around the dropdown, which is positioned with `position: absolute; left: 50%;`, to be able to dynamically center the dropdown ul with `position: relative; left: -50%;`.

Does anyone have a CSS-only solution without that side-effect? If possible, I'm even looking for a solution that works without the *.menuwrapper* div-element, to be able to work with plain nested unordered lists (ul).

Comment: Regarding the wrapper, is the position absolute the only thing in the CSS? Can you post the whole CSS?

Comment: The whole (relevant) css can be found in the _jsfiddle_... :)

Comment: In the html I see <div class="menuwrapper">. I do not see .menuwrapper in the CSS.

Comment: But it is there, line 34. ;) `#main-nav .menuwrapper{position:absolute;left:50%;}`

Comment: Sorry! Sorry! Sorry! it was stuck behind an ID and I didn't see it. IS this fiddle what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/27UE8/5/ I took away the div and moved the dropdown to 0%. The dropdown goes away now when the cursor is just off the color.

Comment: In the above fiddle, I just removed the div styling. In this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/27UE8/6/ - I removed the divs from the html. Seems to work.

Comment: Thank's, but that's not what I want. This way the size of the 1st level node changes when the dropdown menu is too large - and the dropdown menu is too wide, if all 2nd level nodes are smaller than their parent 1st level node. It doesn't work without the absolute positioning and it doesn't center dynamically without the `.menuwrapper` div.

Comment: what about dropping menuwrapper and use transform css ?
http://jsfiddle.net/yjwuvyku/